# Encountered the symbol

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I'm new in oracle pl/sql. I've created new package procedure list then I wanted to realise each procedure in seperate block. Here is list of procedures that I wanted creat for now it's only one.

```
create or replace package listProcedures is

  procedure bss_claim12
  ( o_claim_id out number,
    o_error_code out varchar2,
    o_error_msg out varchar2,
    i_card_number varchar2,
    i_phone_number varchar2,
    i_product_id number,
    i_summ_loan number,
    client_code number,
    mfo varchar2
  );
```

Then I wanted to create it's body but it's  giving following errors.
Compilation errors for PACKAGE BODY IBS.LISTPROCEDURES

> Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting
>   one of the following:

```
create or replace package body ibs.listprocedures is
  procedure bss_claim12
  ( o_claim_id out number,
    o_error_code out varchar2,
    o_error_msg out varchar2,
    i_card_number varchar2,
    i_phone_number varchar2,
    i_product_id number,
    i_summ_loan number,
    client_code number,
    mfo varchar2
) is
 begin
   dbms_output.put_line(o_claim_id);
   dbms_output.put_line(o_error_msg);
   dbms_output.put_line(client_code);
   end bss_claim12;
```

What should i do in body of this procedure to make it work well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `end` both `specification` and `body` parts of the package :

```
SQL> create or replace package listProcedures is
  procedure bss_claim12
  ( o_claim_id out number,
    o_error_code out varchar2,
    o_error_msg out varchar2,
    i_card_number varchar2,
    i_phone_number varchar2,
    i_product_id number,
    i_summ_loan number,
    client_code number,
    mfo varchar2
  );
end listProcedures;
/

SQL> create or replace package body listProcedures is
  procedure bss_claim12
  ( o_claim_id out number,
    o_error_code out varchar2,
    o_error_msg out varchar2,
    i_card_number varchar2,
    i_phone_number varchar2,
    i_product_id number,
    i_summ_loan number,
    client_code number,
    mfo varchar2
  ) is
  begin
     dbms_output.put_line(o_claim_id);
     dbms_output.put_line(o_error_msg);
     dbms_output.put_line(client_code);
  end bss_claim12;
end listProcedures;   
/
```